# Scala how to handle the exception when the key value pair is not available in properties file using scala

Tags: scala

I have the following values in my properties file named `message.properties`

```
gender.type.m=Male
```

i am trying to get the values in my code as below,

```
val Prop = ConfigFactory.load("message.properties")

val value=Prop .getString("gender.type.m")

val value=Prop .getString("gender.type.f")
```

since the value is defined for male in my prop file i am able to get the correct value as male when i pass to my getstring("gender.type.m").

however when i am trying to get the value for female i am getting an exception since the value is not defined for female in my properties file.

could some one help me to handle this exception in scala.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should wrap the property reading in a scala.util.Try:

```
val Prop = ConfigFactory.load("message.properties")

val value= Try(Prop.getString("gender.type.m"))

val value= Try(Prop.getString("gender.type.f"))
```

Now you can deal with the failure case in several ways, depending on how familiar you are with Scala.

If you have default values, you can do something like

```
val Prop = ConfigFactory.load("message.properties")

val value= Try(Prop.getString("gender.type.m")).getOrElse(<defaultValue>)

val value= Try(Prop.getString("gender.type.f")).getOrElse(<defaultValue>)
```

Ideally, you should do something more interesting in case of failure; at least you should log the error probably.

You can also simply fail if there's no such property. If you are familiar with for comprehensions this is a way to do it:

```
val Prop = ConfigFactory.load("message.properties")

for {
 male <- Try(Prop.getString("gender.type.m"))
 female <- Try(Prop.getString("gender.type.f"))
} yield {
  // do something with male and female values
  // if any of them does not exist, then this block won't be executed, and the for comprehension will return a scala.util.Failure

}
```